# Need help with maximum modulus principle and its collorary

Tags: complex-analysis

Theorem: If a function $f$ is analytic and not constant in a given domain D, then $|f(z)|$ has no maximum value in $D$. That is, there is no point $z_0$ in the domain such that $|f(z)| \leq |f(z_0)|$ for all points $z$ in it.

What does it mean to be analytic and not constant?. Does it mean that the function is differentiable in a domain , but it's not something like f(z)=c?$$

Corollary: Suppose that a function f is continuous on a closed bounded region $R$ and that it is analytic and not constant in the interior of $R$. Then the maximum value of $|f(z)|$ in $R$, which is always reached, occurs somewhere on the boundary of $R$ and never in the interior

If f is continuous on a closed bounded region then f is defined everywhere in that region, but what does it mean to be analytic and not constant in the interior R?

Comment: Analytic: has a normally convergent Taylor expansion at each point in its domain of definition.

Holomorphic: is differentiable at every point in its domain of definition.  (Differentiability w.r.t. a complex variable is different from having partial derivatives with respect to two real variables.)

Constant: you understand correctly.

All of the above is explained clearly and concisely in H. Cartan's "Elementary Theory of Analytic Functions".

Comment: what's the difference between analytic and continuous?. If it's analytic then it has to be continuous at a specific point

Comment: Yes, but not vice versa.  See Cartan's book.  The topic really deserves a study, and the book deserves to be chosen as the source.